# Why does Shapes.Item return 0x8004005 error on PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: c++, com, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I first tested this code (simple code to create a new file and delete all the shapes) using PowerPoint 2016. It seems to work just fine:

```
using namespace PowerPoint;

//Load currently running PowerPoint
_ApplicationPtr pptApp;
HRESULT hr = pptApp.GetActiveObject(__uuidof(PowerPoint::Application));

//Create new file with a new slide
_PresentationPtr presEdit = pptApp->Presentations->Add(msoTrue);
_SlidePtr slide = presEdit->Slides->Add(1, PpSlideLayout::ppLayoutText);

//Delete all shapes.
while (slide->Shapes->Count > 0)
{
    //This line seems to give an error in 2007
    PowerPoint::ShapePtr shp = slide->Shapes->Item(1); 
    shp->Delete(); 
}
```

But when I tested it on Powerpoint 2007, something weird happened. When I called the `Shapes->Item` method, it threw a `_com_error` with the error code 0x80004005 (Unspecified Error) with the message `Shapes (unknown member) : Failed.` I searched for this error message and got nothing. I even tried using the 2007 version typelib file, and that didn't work either. After a while, I decided to just revert to using the `IDispatch::Invoke` method (which was a pain) and **that somehow worked**. Not sure why that worked and why my earlier attempts did not.

I'm using `#import` and smart pointers to import the Microsoft Office library into my code.

Comment: Did you have all the service packs installed for 2007? 2007 was flaky when it was first released.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have all the service packs installed (up to SP3). It still fails with the same error.